# How to push data in external json file using typescript?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJQBO.png)
actually I have push data external JSON file

Answer (score 0):

First your jSON file in stored inside the **assets** folder.

```
src/assets/demo.json
```

### JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Senthil",

    },
{
    "Name" : "Periyas"
}
...
]
```

next, create file in your root folder and name it `njson-typings.d.ts` and then paste below code.

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

go to app component folder open the `app.component.ts` file and import the demo file to be displayed.

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import namedata from '../assets/demo.json';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'json-demo';
      Names: any = namedata;
    }
```

then open the `app.component.html` paste the below code.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of Names">
   <div>{{data.Name}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```